# series leds powered with a 6v 4.5ah battery

Tags: led, batteries

I'm running 48 leds with a 6v 4.5AH lead acid battery, there are 24 leds connected in parallel each parellel line has got 2 leds making them 48 leds. the leds are standard 5mm 25cd white leds with 3.2Vf. please i need to know the total current and watt of the leds and how long the battery would last. please ignore the green led color on the attached proteus schematic, the illustration is to show how the leds are arranged.
[image]

Comment: How do you expect people to figure out the current with no resistance or a datasheet for the LED?

Comment: the resistor is 15R/10W and the LED is a standard 5mm white led with 3.2Vf and 20mA

Comment: Still need the datasheet for the LED. saying it's 3.2Vf when you're giving it 6V isn't going to make it easy to figure out the current. Could really do with seeing a Vf vs mA curve. Also is there a resistor in series with every branch or just the one resistor?

Comment: the datasheet http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1386632.pdf

Comment: @mcGeek: Answer _all_ his requests for information. You have only answered one.

Comment: I gave a 15R/10W resistor and included the datasheet, those were what he requested for. and what if the forward voltage is 2.8Vf would it do?

Comment: Is there a resistor on each branch? That's the last bit of info I'm after

Comment: No its not, its on the connecting anode line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, running two identical loads in parallel doubles the current, while keeping the same voltage. Running those loads in series doubles the voltage, but maintaining the same current. So, what you're looking at here is, based on the comment you provided:

1. Each serial "substring" of two LEDs will drive at full power when they are provided with 6.4V and 20mA, or 128mW.
2. Because you have 24 substrings, your power consumption is simply $$N \cdot P_{d(string)}$$, so 24 * 128mW = 3.072W. Stated in terms of voltage and current, this gives 6.4V at 480mA.

You can go about getting the (ideal/naïve) operation time from the battery through a number of ways. The first is to round down the 6.4V string voltage to 6.0V, your battery voltage (sealed-lead acid?), and then divide 4,500mA by the *current* consumption. This would give **9.3 hours**.

The second is to multiply the battery voltage and current to get the energy capacity in watt-hours (Wh), and then divide that by the *power* consumption to pull out the running time. This gives **8.8 hours**, because it uses a number based on the full Vf of the LED, not the maximum voltage the battery can supply.

There are two big problems with these methods, hence the requests for access to datasheets in your comments. The first is that the current consumption, call it If, of an LED depends on the Vf. Obviously, your battery cannot supply any more voltage than what it is rated for (or, at least you should be designing with that restriction), so your If @ 6.0V is going to be less than what it would be at 6.4V. The datasheet is needed because it keeps a graph of forward voltage and forward current as one (usually voltage) changes.

The second big problem is that a battery is not an *ideal voltage source*; as it depletes, the rail voltage (and current availability) of your circuit will also drop, affecting the current draw (and thus the power consumption) of the LEDs. Because of this, actual runtime might be significantly different than those "eyeball" estimates above.

Comment: here is a datasheet  http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1386632.pdf

Comment: would a 5mm 2.8Vf 20mA LED work?

Comment: @mcGeek based on that datasheet, at 6.0V, your (initial) battery rail voltage, you're looking at 10mA of consumption rather than 20mA at 6.4V. You can then rework the above calculations backwards to find the runtime. As to the 2.8V/20mA, that would allow the LED strings to draw more power, but because the LED strings would have a series Vf lower than your battery, you'd need series resistors for safety.

Comment: @mcGeek the formula for current-limiting resistors is generally \$\Delta V / I\$, or in this case, \$(V_{batt} - V_f) / I_f\$. You then find the current drop with \$I^2R\$. So, this gives 20 ohms for the resistance and about 8mW for the power handling capability of each resistor (most through-hole resistors are at least 1/4 or 1/8W to put that in perspective). This can be extended to the entire circuit (one between one terminal and the battery), but will have to be much beefier to dissipate much more power.

Answer (score 2):

Your battery does not provide sufficient voltage to meet your white LED requirements.  Two white LEDs in series have a Vf of 6.4V, while your battery is only 6.0V, and that does not include the drop across the current limiting resistor.

If driven at 3.2 V each and allowed 20 mA each, as rated, then each LED would dissipate 64 mW, each branch would 128 mW, and the 48x LED array would dissipate 3.072 W.

Your battery, at 6.0 V with 4.5 Ah, can provide 27 Watt-hours of energy.  Your "ideal" LED array would last about 8 hours 47 minutes.  This "ideal" calculation does not calculate a current limiting resistor (or 24 of them, if each LED pair has one) and assumes the LEDs can actually be driven by the battery, and does not account for voltage drop of the battery over time.

Comment: what if i use a 5mm 2.8Vf 20mA LED would it work?

Answer (score 1):

If your battery is directly connected to the 'LED' jumper on the right the total current will be very hard to predict.

The current is, in this case, determined by the internal battery resistance and the forward voltage of the series in every working point (it hugely varies during battery discharge, but not less important to consider is temperature).

To make any sort of prediction you need at least measure the total current once, maybe at full battery charge. In this condition you can obtain the ideal battery duration simply by dividing its capacity by the total current:

\$ T_{ON} = \frac{C_{bat}}{I_{tot}} \$

Remind that in this case you're using

\$ [T_{ON}] = \$ hours

\$ [C_{bat}] = \$ hours \$ \cdot \$ A

For example, measuring a total current of 0.5 A you'll get

\$ T_{ON} = \frac{4.5 Ah}{0.5 A} = 9 \$ hours

Real battery duration is going to be something more due to the current collapsing during the discharging process. Nominal battery duration is uncertainty-affected so take this result as indicative.

I imagine the circuit works in some way, varying its luminosity with time, but consider that it only relies on the internal battery resistance and with a small over-voltage (different battery type) you could destroy half of the leds at once.

What you can do is limiting the current value with a resistor for each series.